# Meteor: Spacebars not updating on session-value change

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I have this html-File in Meteor

```
{{#if thevalue}}
    {{> one}}
{{else}}
    {{> two}}
{{/if}}
```

and this helper

```
'thevalue': Session.get('thevalue') //returns true or false
```

My problem is that when the Session-Value changes, the if/else-Bracktes from Spacebars do not change with it. I thought Session-Values are reactive...but maybe I have some sort of misconception how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write your helper as a function like so

```
'thevalue': function () {
  return Session.get('thevalue');
}
```

See the docs [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Session is reactive and helper is a reactive computation. The problem may be the format of your helper which should be like this:

```
  thevalue: function(){
      return Session.get('thevalue');
    }
```

The problem could simply be that you are putting 'thevalue' in quotes and turning it in to a string where I believe it needs to run as a function.

Keep in mind if your 'thevalue' is 0 then your spacebars will return {{> two}}.